# I am getting an Unhandled exception error when my application tries to load 10000 records in dynamic grid control

Tags: visual-c++

i am working on VC++ application, where all remit transactions are displaying in one of dynamic grid control. User has to double click on that master grid control and then detail window gets popup. In that detail level transactions are displayed for that master entry. (it's like drill down detail level). Now in this detail window grid control, first time only 1000 records are displaying. To display next 10000 records in dynamic grid ctrl, user clicked on 'Get Next' button. Here is the point that application goes in error:

**"Unhanded exception at 0x78594826 in Qpay.exe: 0x800000x26: A long jump has been executed."** and application got closed.

Application uses Oracel11g db.

Some times it error message is like "Unhandled exception error..." and below error code displays:

---

```
See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************
System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
   at ATL.CStringT<char,StrTraitMFC_DLL<char,ATL::ChTraitsCRT<char> > >.=(CStringT<char\,StrTraitMFC_DLL<char\,ATL::ChTraitsCRT<char> > >* , Byte* )
   at CRemDetail.PopulateDatatblctrl1(CRemDetail* )
   at CRemDetail.OnInitDialog(CRemDetail* )
   at CRemDetail.SCOnRemDetail(CRemDetail* , UserInfoStruct* pUserInfo, Int32 lSolar, InputDetailStruct Inputs, Int32 m_lSecCode)
   at CRemUnrelDlg.OnCellDoubleClick(CRemUnrelDlg* , Object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
   at CRemUnrelDlg.delegate_proxy_type.OnCellDoubleClick(Object arg0, DataGridViewCellEventArgs arg1)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnCellDoubleClick(DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnDoubleClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ActiveXImpl.System.Windows.Forms.IWindowTarget.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)


************** Loaded Assemblies **************
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.3643 (GDR.050727-3600)
    CodeBase: file:///c:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v2.0.50727/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
Qpay
    Assembly Version: 0.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2, 0, 0, 0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/qpay/Qpay.exe
----------------------------------------
msvcm80
    Assembly Version: 8.0.50727.6195
    Win32 Version: 8.00.50727.6195
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/WinSxS/x86_Microsoft.VC80.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.6195_x-ww_44262b86/msvcm80.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.3645 (GDR.050727-3600)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.3644 (GDR.050727-3600)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.3644 (GDR.050727-3600)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
MFCM90
    Assembly Version: 9.0.30729.0
    Win32 Version: 9.00.30729.6161
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/WinSxS/x86_Microsoft.VC90.MFC_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.6161_x-ww_028bc148/MFCM90.dll
----------------------------------------
msvcm90
    Assembly Version: 9.0.30729.6161
    Win32 Version: 9.00.30729.6161
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/WinSxS/x86_Microsoft.VC90.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.6161_x-ww_31a54e43/msvcm90.dll
----------------------------------------
Accessibility
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.3053 (netfxsp.050727-3000)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Accessibility/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Accessibility.dll
----------------------------------------
CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine
    Assembly Version: 10.5.3700.0
    Win32 Version: 10.5.0.1943
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine/10.5.3700.0__692fbea5521e1304/CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.dll
----------------------------------------
CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 10.5.3700.0
    Win32 Version: 10.5.0.1943
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms/10.5.3700.0__692fbea5521e1304/CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
CrystalDecisions.Shared
    Assembly Version: 10.5.3700.0
    Win32 Version: 10.5.0.1943
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/CrystalDecisions.Shared/10.5.3700.0__692fbea5521e1304/CrystalDecisions.Shared.dll
----------------------------------------
CrystalDecisions.ReportSource
    Assembly Version: 10.5.3700.0
    Win32 Version: 10.5.0.1943
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/CrystalDecisions.ReportSource/10.5.3700.0__692fbea5521e1304/CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Configuration
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.3053 (netfxsp.050727-3000)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xml
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.3082 (QFE.050727-3000)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Web
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.3634 (GDR.050727-3600)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_32/System.Web/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Web.dll
----------------------------------------
CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CommLayer
    Assembly Version: 10.5.3700.0
    Win32 Version: 10.5.0.1943
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CommLayer/10.5.3700.0__692fbea5521e1304/CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CommLayer.dll
----------------------------------------
CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc
    Assembly Version: 10.5.3700.0
    Win32 Version: 10.5.0.1943
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc/10.5.3700.0__692fbea5521e1304/CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Data
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.3053 (netfxsp.050727-3000)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_32/System.Data/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.dll
----------------------------------------
CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataSetConversion
    Assembly Version: 10.5.3700.0
    Win32 Version: 10.5.0.1943
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataSetConversion/10.5.3700.0__692fbea5521e1304/CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataSetConversion.dll
----------------------------------------
CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel
    Assembly Version: 10.5.3700.0
    Win32 Version: 10.5.0.1943
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel/10.5.3700.0__692fbea5521e1304/CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel.dll
----------------------------------------
CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers
    Assembly Version: 10.5.3700.0
    Win32 Version: 10.5.0.1943
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers/10.5.3700.0__692fbea5521e1304/CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers.dll
----------------------------------------
CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportDefModel
    Assembly Version: 10.5.3700.0
    Win32 Version: 10.5.0.1943
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportDefModel/10.5.3700.0__692fbea5521e1304/CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportDefModel.dll
----------------------------------------
CrystalDecisions.KeyCode
    Assembly Version: 10.5.3700.0
    Win32 Version: 10.5.0.1943
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/CrystalDecisions.KeyCode/10.5.3700.0__692fbea5521e1304/CrystalDecisions.KeyCode.dll
----------------------------------------
CustomMarshalers
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.3053 (netfxsp.050727-3000)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_32/CustomMarshalers/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/CustomMarshalers.dll
----------------------------------------
CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.XmlSerialize
    Assembly Version: 10.5.3700.0
    Win32 Version: 10.5.0.1943
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.XmlSerialize/10.5.3700.0__692fbea5521e1304/CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.XmlSerialize.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Web.Services
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.3053 (netfxsp.050727-3000)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Web.Services/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Web.Services.dll
----------------------------------------
CrystalDecisions.Web
    Assembly Version: 10.5.3700.0
    Win32 Version: 10.5.0.1943
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/CrystalDecisions.Web/10.5.3700.0__692fbea5521e1304/CrystalDecisions.Web.dll
----------------------------------------
CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Framework
    Assembly Version: 10.5.3700.0
    Win32 Version: 10.5.0.268
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC/CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Framework/10.5.3700.0__692fbea5521e1304/CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Framework.dll
----------------------------------------

************** JIT Debugging **************
To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this
application or computer (machine.config) must have the
jitDebugging value set in the system.windows.forms section.
The application must also be compiled with debugging
enabled.

For example:

<configuration>
    <system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />
</configuration>

When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception
will be sent to the JIT debugger registered on the computer
rather than be handled by this dialog box.
```

---

Comment: Right there at the top of your stack trace, it says "This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt."  Unfortunately, finding a memory corruption bug is not a simple task.

Comment: That "long jump" probably describes the user's action when faced with the job of having to claw through ten thousand records.  The call stack however just shows an access violation, the standard way in which code that uses pointers fails.  With non-zero odds that the heap was corrupted earlier in code that doesn't have anything to do with what you see in the stack trace.  Ask the programmer or company that wrote "CRemDetail" for help.